# unable to delete temporary file with python

Tags: python, linux, django

I am using django views, I create a temp_dir using `tempfile.gettempdir()`.

I write a gzipped text file in there, and then scp the file elsewhere.  When these tasks are complete I try to delete the temp_dir.

```
 if os.path.exists( temp_dir ):
      shutil.rmtree( temp_dir )
```

However, occasionally I get this error back:

```
 Operation not permitted: '/tmp/.ICE-unix'
```

Any ideas what this error means and how to best handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tempfile.gettempdir() does not create a temp directory - it returns your system's standand tmp directory. DO NOT DELETE IT! That will blow everybody's temp files away. You can delete the file you created inside the temp dir, or you can create your own temp dir, but leave this one alone.

Answer (score 0):

The value for temp_dir is taken from the OS environment variables, and apparently some other process is also using it to create files. The other file might be in use/locked and that will prevent you from deleting it.
Q: What is /tmp/.ICE-unix ?
A: Its a directory where X-windows session information is saved.

Answer (score -1):

I am no expert but try running the python program or what your using to do this as an administrator then it will most likely allow this process to be done...

Comment: ...which is a good reason why we shouldn't run as root! (smile)